# detect the zoom with the jquery-ui-map

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the Google maps v3 plugin for jQuery. All I want to do is to detect the zoom. With the code below

```
 var map = $('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'map');
$(map).addEventListener('zoom_changed', function() {
    alert(map);
});
```

I can detect if the zoom has changed but I don't know the exact zoom. So, how can I detect the zoom?

Comment: @undefined Can you please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: @undefined yes, but gmap is **not** a jQuery object.... (at least from the context of this question)

Comment: @undefined - it's some sort of plugin that lets you use the Google Maps functions on jQuery objects, I think?? It's wrapped in jQuery so it's definetively a jQuery object.

Comment: This isn't working because you're probably doing it outside of the initialisation function and as such, it's unable to bind to a `map` element because it's not loaded.. `console.log(map)`; i'm willing to bet it's undefined...

Comment: I haven't used `gmap` plugin, but `$()` returns a jQuery object and it doesn't have `addEventListener` method!?

Answer (score 0):

There is probable an event variable passed in there.

Try using it:

```
var map = $('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'map');
$(map).addEventListener('zoom_changed', function(event) {
    alert(map);
    //... use event
});
```